# Transfrom list of dicts to complex excel structure

Tags: python, excel, formatting, export-to-excel, data-manipulation

I have manipulated data into a list of dicts that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Name-A": {
            "Sub Name-A": {
                "Max": 200,
                "date": {
                    "2022-06-06": {
                        "Time Series": 123,
                        "Probability": 0.2,
                        "A": 1,
                        "B": 2
                    },
                    "2022-06-07": {
                        "Time Series": 245,
                        "Probability": 0.4,
                        "A": 4,
                        "B": 5
                    },
                    "2022-06-08": {
                        "Time Series": 789,
                        "Probability": 0.99,
                        "A": 7,
                        "B": 8
                    },
                    "2022-07-19": {
                        "Time Series": 136,
                        "Probability": 0.1,
                        "A": 10,
                        "B": 11
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {   
        "Name-B": {
            "Sub Name-B1": {
                "Max": 400,
                "date": {
                    "2022-06-06": {
                        "Time Series": 123,
                        "Probability": 0.2,
                        "A": 1,
                        "B": 2
                    },
                    "2022-06-07": {
                        "Time Series": 245,
                        "Probability": 0.4,
                        "A": 4,
                        "B": 5
                    },
                    "2022-06-08": {
                        "Time Series": 789,
                        "Probability": 0.99,
                        "A": 7,
                        "B": 8
                    },
                    "2022-07-19": {
                        "Time Series": 136,
                        "Probability": 0.1,
                        "A": 10,
                        "B": 11
                    }
                }
            },
            "Sub Name-B2": {
                "Max": 800,
                "date": {
                    "2022-06-06": {
                        "Time Series": 123,
                        "Probability": 0.2,
                        "A": 1,
                        "B": 2
                    },
                    "2022-06-07": {
                        "Time Series": 245,
                        "Probability": 0.4,
                        "A": 4,
                        "B": 5
                    },
                    "2022-06-08": {
                        "Time Series": 789,
                        "Probability": 0.99,
                        "A": 7,
                        "B": 8
                    },
                    "2022-07-19": {
                        "Time Series": 136,
                        "Probability": 0.1,
                        "A": 10,
                        "B": 11
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

This is just dummy data, but basically imagine this over 10,000+ lines. Similar schema throughout. I need to generate an excel worksheet from this data that should look something like:

[image: Excel Sample Spreadsheet]

I have been trying multiple solutions. When I convert the list of dicts to a Pandas Dataframe it looks completely different. Have tried looping over to extract the headers, but that's also an issue since I cannot hardcode the values as the data length is always variable. Any ideas/guidance on how I can achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Currently trying to do something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

file_path = "test_output.xlsx"


name_to_sub_name = defaultdict(list)
time_series_cols = ['Time Series', 'Probability', 'A', 'B', 'C']

req_chunks = 0
for each_chunk in record:
    for name, all_data in each_chunk.items():
        for sub_name, each_data in all_data.items():
            name_to_sub_name[name].append(sub_name)
            req_chunks += 1

with Workbook(file_path) as workbook:
    first_col = 1
    entity_row = 0
    cp_row = 2
    worksheet_main = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet_main.write(entity_row+1, first_col-1, "date")
    for name, list_of_cps in name_to_sub_name.items():
        for sub_name in list_of_cps:
            worksheet_main.write(entity_row, first_col, name)
            worksheet_main.write(entity_row, first_col+1, sub_name)

            for each_timeseries in time_series_cols:
                worksheet_main.write(entity_row+1, first_col, each_timeseries)
                entity_row = 0
                first_col += 1
            first_col += 1
```

I managed to dynamically create the columns as intended, but don't know how to populate them from my dictionary. There has to be an easier way to do this, maybe `pandas` but currently, I am not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: one option can be to convert the dictionary to json and than json to html table using freely available online tools, the html table can be copy pasted in excel as well.

Comment: what do you mean by data length is always different? Do you have different dates and need to adjust for that or do you have different number of columns in the sub name spaces?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the python package `xlsxwriter`  for this:

Example working on your dict (quick and dirty):

```
import xlsxwriter
from datetime import datetime

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Data')

#data = dict provided in question

#write first column
dates = list(list(list(data[0].items())[0][1].items())[0][1]['date'].keys())
dates = [datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d') for d in dates]
date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yy',
                                     'align': 'left'})

worksheet.write(3, 0,'Date')

for e, date in enumerate(dates):
    worksheet.write_datetime(3+e,0,date,date_format)

#get the different Data column names and save them    
data_names = list(next(iter(list(list(data[0].items())[0][1].items())[0][1]['date'].items()))[1].keys())


#iterate over the dict and write at the necessary time to the cells
col = 1
for d0 in data:
    for k1 in d0.keys():
        d1 = d0[k1]

        for k2 in d1.keys():
            worksheet.write(0,col,k1)
            worksheet.write(1,col,k2)
            
            col_subset = col
            for name in data_names:
                worksheet.write(2,col_subset,name)
                col_subset+=1
            
            d2 = d1[k2]
            worksheet.write(2,col_subset,'C')
            worksheet.write(3,col_subset,d2['Max'])

            row = 3
            for date in d2['date'].keys():
                d3 = d2['date'][date]
                
                col_subset = col
                for name in data_names:
                    worksheet.write(row, col_subset, d3[name])
                    col_subset+=1
                    
                row+=1
        
            col += len(data_names)+3

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

My reaction is that the json representation is way off from being optimal for such rendition, you might want to relook into alternate structures.

Anyway, I'm not a python person, but from an algorithm perspective, here's what you can do (pseudo code) :

Assumption:

1. You can define a function that writes to the (r,c) cell of the target excel sheet

```
function Write2Cell(row:number, col:number,text:string)
```

2. Given a section data, there's a function firstProp which gives the first property of the json object.

```
/* Writes a full section & returns the maximum column that this section has consumed.
*/
function WriteASection(row,col, data ) {
  r = row;
  c = col;
  name = firstProp(data); // = Name-A
  name_data = data[name];
  subName = firstProp(name_data); // Sub Name-A
  subName_data = name_data[subName];

  Write2Cell(r,c+1,name);
  Write2Cell(r+1,c+1, subName);

  max_cols_added = 0; // track max. cols consumed
  rH = r +  2; // data header starts in this row
  r2 = r + 3; // data rows starts in this row
  max_found = null;

  foreach_keys( F in subName_data ) {
    if(F == "Max") max_found = subName_data[F];
    else { // now comes the listing out each column
      needHeaders = true;
      date_data = subName_data[F];
      foreach_keys(curr_date in date_data) {
        curr_date_data = date_data[curr_date];
        Write2Cell(r2,c,curr_date);
        i = 0;
        foreach_keys( K in curr_date_data) {
          Write2Cell(r2,c+i,curr_date_data[K]);
          if(needHeaders) {
            Write2Cell(rH,c+i,K);
          }
          i++;
        }
        needHeaders = false; // first row rendition does header
        if(i > max_cols_added) {
          max_cols_added = i;
        }
        r2++;
      }
    }
  }
  Write2Cell(rH+1,c+max_cols_added,curr_date_data[K]); 
  max_cols_added++; // we want to add the max

  return max_cols_added;
}
```

3. Once you have these two functions done, then its simple

```
row = 1;
col = 0;
for( data in DataList ) {
  col++;
  row = 1; // every section starts from 1st row 
  col = WriteASection(row, col, data); // note we use the max col returned
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate exactly the output attached by you in the excel screenshot, given the example input list (called `record` in my code).

I wrote this script using [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and Pandas.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.cell import coordinate_from_string, column_index_from_string
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

file_path = Path('.')/'test_output.xlsx'

wb = Workbook()

ws1 = wb.active

is_first = True
col_names = 2
col_data_init = 2

for chunk in record:
    for name_0, value_0 in chunk.items():
        for name_1, value_1 in value_0.items():

            # read data
            df = pd.DataFrame(value_1)

            df = pd.concat(
                [df.loc[:,['Max']].reset_index(),pd.json_normalize(df['date'])],
                axis=1
            ).rename({'index':'Date','Max':'C'},axis=1)
            
            # date column
            if is_first: 
                ws1.cell(row=3,column=1).value = 'Date'
                row_date = 4
                for date_value in df['Date'].to_list():
                    ws1.cell(row=row_date,column=1).value = date_value
                    row_date+=1
                is_first = False

            # write chunk names
            ws1.cell(row=1,column=col_names).value = name_0
            ws1.cell(row=2,column=col_names).value = name_1
            col_names+=7

            # write dataframe columns ['Time Series', 'Probability','A','B']
            row_data_id = 3
            col_data_id = col_data_init
            for df_row in dataframe_to_rows(df.loc[:,['Time Series', 'Probability','A','B']],index=False):
                for df_value in df_row:
                    ws1.cell(row=row_data_id,column=col_data_id).value=df_value
                    col_data_id += 1
                row_data_id += 1
                col_data_id = col_data_init

            # write dataframe columns ['C']
            ws1.cell(row=3,column=col_data_init+4).value = 'C'
            ws1.cell(row=4,column=col_data_init+4).value = df['C'].iloc[0]

            col_data_init += 7
            
wb.save(str(file_path))

wb.close()
```

It outputs an excel file (called test_output.xlsx), structured like this
[image: Sample output]

Notice that I made some assumptions:

- the dictionary inside each subgroup is always structured in the same way
- the dates are the same in each subgroup

It should work for any data length (i.e., any number of dates), and for any number of groups/subgroups.